# Why are the output results different？

Tags: javascript

```js
async function fn1() {
  return 1
}
async function fn2() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}

function fn3() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}

function fn4() {
  return Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(1))
}
console.log(fn1()); //Promise {<fulfilled>: 1}
console.log(fn2()); // Promise {<pending>}
console.log(fn3()); // Promise {<fulfilled>: 1}
console.log(fn4()); // Promise {<fulfilled>: 1}
```

When I run fn2(), it outputs `Promise { pending }`.

Why is fn2() `Promise { pending }` rather than `Promise {fulfilled: 1}`?

Comment: Don't look at this too deeply, the behaviour is not very relevant for real code.

Comment: They're all promises, and they'll all behave as they're supposed to when you treat them as you're supposed to: `console.log(await fnX())` or `fnX().then(console.log)`. The rest are implementation details.

Comment: (edited into a snippet, but one still has to open the JS console of a browser to actually see the effect)

Answer (score 0):

`fn2()` is kinda deceiving.  Returning a Promise from an `async` function results in code that MUST be `await`ed or `then()`ed before it even tries to resolve.  [Here's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-event-loop-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-in-javascript) a starting point to understand why.

**EDIT**: This is incorrect.  See @VLAZ's comment below.

Comment: Don't think you need to `await` or call the `then` method on a promise for it to be resolved.

Comment: "*Returning a Promise from an async function results in code that MUST be awaited or then()ed before it even tries to resolve.*"  This is ***COMPLETELY*** incorrect. Promises are markers for async operations. There is **no relation at all** between an async task being set in motion and handling a promise. Async operations do not "start" when you do something with a promise, the same way they cannot be ended by handling a promise. `await`-ing or `.then()`-ing a promise does not do anything with the task, just lets the code react to the task finishing.

Comment: That does make sense.  I definitely need to review Promise internals, then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Async function always return a promise. So

Fn2 function returning two promise one by async function and one by your return statement.

And return statement will full fill the  async function promise and will not full fill the return statement promise that is why you are getting this output

Answer (score 0):

Both `function1` and `function2` are async, but in case of function 1 you are directly returning the value where as in `function2` you are returning a promise. `Promise` always returns a promise in either case(resolve or reject). Before the promise could resolve,`function2` has already returned the statement. You could use `await` for promise to either resolve or reject before returning the value.